# messages.send ошибка при отправке сообщения нескольким людям

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

```
href="https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_ids=
<?php echo $row['nums'];?>
&message=<?php echo $row['text']; ?>
&v=5.37&access_token=<?php echo $row['token']; ?>
```

- NUMS - это айдишники пользователей
- text - текст для отправки
- token - токен api vk

Почему я могу отправить одному человеку, а нескольким -  нет?

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `user_ids` в `messages.send` доступен только при отправке сообщений в диалогах группы от ее имени, а у вас `access_token`, видимо, создан от имени пользователя

Answer (score 0):

А не проще будет сделать так?

```
$idsFile = __DIR__ . '/user_id.txt'; //Файл с ID
$idsStr = file_get_contents($idsFile);
$ids = array_filter(explode("\n", $idsStr)); //разбиваем ID

foreach ($ids as $value) {$messages_send = array( //Перебираем ID и отправляем на все сообщение.

            'message' => "Hello World",
            'user_id' => $value,
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'v' => '5.0');

$get = http_build_query($messages_send);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.$get);
}
```

PS. Ты где-то **`foreach`** потерял =)